# VerneMQ Configuration file cannot be generated

Tags: mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

When I deploy VerneMQ to my local MiniKube Kubernetes cluster using its official Helm chart, I am getting the following error:

**Permissions ok: Our pod my-vernemq-0 belongs to StatefulSet my-vernemq with 1 replicas**

**Error generating config with cuttlefish**

**run `vernemq config generate -l debug` for more information.**

Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from release 1.13.0, the official Docker images work for ARM64 systems. https://hub.docker.com/r/vernemq/vernemq

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that I am using vernemq docker linux/amd64 image on M1 Mac. But unfortunately, currently we do not have the official ARM64 image. However, we can use this image instead: https://github.com/ysoftwareab/docker-vernemq/pkgs/container/docker-vernemq

Please refer to this for more information: https://github.com/vernemq/vernemq/issues/1421